# Resizing with a max width/height while keeping the original ratio using Intervention Image in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image-manipulation

I want to constrain an image only if they exceed **either** maximum dimensions while keeping the original ratio intact.

So let's say my parameters are a max height and width of 600.

An image of 1000x1000 would become 600x600, simple enough.

An image of 2000x1000 would become 600x300. This would mean that the highest of the two values becomes 600, while the other gets constrained proportionally.

Something like this

```
            $image->resize(600, 600, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

**EDIT:**

As per the comments, I tried this:

```
    $medium = Image::make($file);

    $medium->resize(null, 500, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });

    $medium->resize(500, null, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });             
    $medium->save( public_path('/uploads/artistUploads/medium-' . $filename , 90) );
```

This does not work. Only the first resize is applied, which in this case is width.

HOWEVER, turns out the original code does work. I simply assumed it wouldn't, but it does.

Comment: Thanks for posting your findings, it helped me out

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I know I am somewhat late to the race, but I have the answer you are looking for:

```
$width = 600; // your max width
$height = 600; // your max height
$img = IMG::make($uploaded_file);
$img->height() > $img->width() ? $width=null : $height=null;
$img->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
```

> An image of 1000x1000 would become 600x600.
>
> An image of 2000x1000 would become 600x300. This would mean that the
>   highest of the two values becomes 600, while the other gets
>   constrained proportionally.

This is what this code does. Hope I can help someone.

Comment: Good answer from someone who actually understood the problem.  I've been able to simplify it even further:  `$resized = ($img->height() > $img->width() ? $img->heighten($max_height) : $img->widen($max_width));`

Answer (score 14):

As according to the [Image Intervention Docs](http://image.intervention.io/api/resize), you can do this in 3 simple ways

```
// resize the image to a width of 300 and constraint aspect ratio (auto height)
$img->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

// resize the image to a height of 200 and constraint aspect ratio (auto width)
$img->resize(null, 200, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

// prevent possible upsizing
$img->resize(null, 400, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
    $constraint->upsize();
});
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I mean, not really. Are you saying that I should first constrain the height then the width? In a 2000x1000 scenario with 600 max, would this bring it to 600x300?

Comment: @FelixMaxime Yup in the case of defined width, the width parameter is compromised and the solution would be 600x300 whereas if the height is defined and width is given as null then the height param is compromised to 1200x600.

Comment: It doesn't work. It only does the first one (in this case, width).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`widen()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/widen) and [`heighten()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/heighten) methods.

`widen()`:

> Resizes the current image to new width, constraining aspect ratio. Pass an optional Closure callback as third parameter, to apply additional constraints like preventing possible upsizing.

`heighten()`:

> Resizes the current image to new height, constraining aspect ratio. Pass an optional Closure callback as third parameter, to apply additional constraints like preventing possible upsizing.

Or you could use `aspectRatio()` constraint. Examples from [`resize()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/resize) documentation:

```
// resize the image to a width of 300 and constrain aspect ratio (auto height)
$img->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

// resize the image to a height of 200 and constrain aspect ratio (auto width)
$img->resize(null, 200, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
```

Comment: Why widen and heighten? I'm trying to downsize.

Comment: @FelixMaxime, why are you thinking it's for upsizing? )

Comment: Because of the dictionary definition of those terms. Maybe they mean something else in Intervention.

Comment: @FelixMaxime, well, these methods do exactly what you need, so as `resize()` with constraints.

Answer (score 0):

This is my template for doing similar work

```
<?php

namespace App\ImageSize;

use Intervention\Image\Image;
use Intervention\Image\Filters\FilterInterface;

class Large implements FilterInterface
{
    public function applyFilter(Image $image)
    {
        $w = $image->width();
        $h = $image->height();
        if($w > $h) {
            $image->resize(1000, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
        } else {
            $image->resize(null, 1000, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
        }

        return $image;

    }
}
```